# XSLT template use XML value as table row 'bgcolor'

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, xml-serialization

I have an XSLT template for an email. I want to be able to specifiy the overall template colour (which is set on various table cells etc.), so one of the fields I'm passing to the template is a ReportHexColour C# property - a hex colour string (e.g #4F81BD).

```
public string ReportColourHex { get; set; }
```

No matter what I do, this value will not be placed in the `bgcolor` attribute of the  element in the template (or the the `td style="background-color:..."` attribute for that matter).

After scouting the internet I've tried:

```
 <td bgcolor="{BuildReportData/ReportColourHex}" style="font-weight: bold">
```

as well as:

```
<td style="font-weight: bold>
    <xsl:attribute name="bgcolor">
        <xsl:value-of select="BuildReportData/ReportColourHex" />
    </xsl:attribute>
    ... other text here etc.
</td>
```

Both of these ideas do nothing. The HTML that is generated for the row background is always white (but if I inspect the source of the email, the bgcolor actually has no value i.e. it looks like this: `<td bgcolor=""`

First thought obviously is that the data isn't there. However, I can render out `<xsl:value-of select="BuildReportData/ReportColourHex" />` anywhere else in the template and the value appears correclty as text in the final email. This one is driving me a bit mad - so any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Show your source XML and the context around the td as well, please.

Comment: Please post enough details allowing us to reproduce the problem. Also explain whether the problem is simply that the resulting HTML is not rendered with the background color you want or whether the resulting HTML document really does have an empty `bgcolor` attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've literally just stumbled across this. It's all about scope in my XSLT template.I was trying to access the `BuildReportData/ReportColourHex` value from inside a `xsl:for-each` loop. As soon as I declared a variable outside the loop to hold the ReportColourHex value, it worked perfectly.

Sorry for the time waste!